How to collapse or better organize long Jupyter notebook cells in Pycharm IDE?
I'm working with long Jupyter notebooks (.ipynb files) that contain numerous cells and outputs, and it's becoming cumbersome to navigate through them in PyCharm. The IDE doesn't seem to natively support cell collapsing, which makes managing the notebook quite difficult.
Are there any plugins, settings, or workarounds to better organize or collapse cells in PyCharm? How can I make my notebook file more manageable within this IDE?

A workaround to make the cells collapsible is to surround the cell content with region (makes any code inside collapsible):
# region <description>
<code>
# endregion

PS: regions can be also nested and there is xml like variant:
# <editor-fold desc="...description...">
...code...
# </editor-fold>



This isn't working with the jupyter notebook file in pycharm. I doubt if @icaine understood the question :/

Heh,what? I am also the one who made the question as i couldn't find an answer for it and after some time i managed to found at least some workaround..
